# How to properly format timestamp

Tags: python

I have the following info for timestamp from the database:

```
time_format: str = "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M %Z"
timestamp = '2020-11-03T21:32:19.722012+00:00' 
timezone = 'America/New_York'
```

How can I use datetime to format this information to look as follows:

```
11/03/2020 17:32EST
```

I was able to get this far:

```
datetime.datetime.now().fromisoformat(timestamp_utc).strftime(time_format)
```

But can't figure out how to replace datetime.now() with any time and then display the desired timezone in place of "UTC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As python doens't have fantastic timezone support out of the box I'd recommend the [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) library for this use case.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# Input
datetime_str = '2020-11-03T21:32:19.722012+00:00'
timezone_str = 'America/New_York'
output_format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %Z'

# Convert input datetime str to python datetime obj
# this datetime is timezone aware, with tz=UTC
utc_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat(datetime_str)

# Convert input timezone str to a pytz timezone object
new_timezone = pytz.timezone(timezone_str)

# Adjust the UTC datetime to use the new timezone
new_timezone_datetime = utc_datetime.astimezone(new_timezone)

# Print in the desired output format
print(new_timezone_datetime.strftime(output_format))
```

If I run the above code, I get the following...

```
11/03/2020 16:32 EST
```

**EDIT:** The reason it is `16:32` instead of `17:32` is because `American/New_York` is the same as `US/Eastern`, in that they use `EST`/`EDT` at different points during the year (daylight savings). `2020-11-03` happens to fall in `EST`.